# Return ordered eigenvalues and eigenvectors with `numpy.linalg.eig`

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

When running `np.linalg.eig([[0, 1], [1, 0]])` I get the following output:

```
(array([ 1., -1.]),
 array([[ 0.70710678, -0.70710678],
        [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]]))
```

This is correct, however, the order of the eigenvalues doesn't correspond to the order of the eigenvectors. That is to say, the eigenvalue at index `0` corresponds to the eigenvector at index `1` and viceversa.

Is there any *easy* way to fix this? I could use the eigenvectors to calculate their corresponding eigenvalues directly, but that wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) tells you the eigenvectors are the columns not the rows, which I admit is pretty surprising. `The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].`

Comment: @KyleParsons oh I see, that makes sense. Kind of weird output format, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @KyleParsons' comment, I figured out what was the problem. The eigenvectors are represented by the columns, not the rows. Thus, to get the output I wanted, I can simply do:

```py
A = # whatever matrix
vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(A)
vecs = vecs.tranpose()
```